# Did Elsie catch the runaway spirit (kaketama) that was in Nagase Jun?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

In *The World God Only Knows 2 (Kami nomi zo Shiru Sekai II)* episode 11 around 23:00, we can see kaketama of Nagase running away. After that, there is no information about that kaketama. It also doesn't show if Elsie catching the kaketama.

What happened to that kaketama? Did Elsie catch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's ever shown in anime but in manga we see Elsie caught it.

From manga, The World God Only Knows, chapter 42 "A Demon That's Tiny = The Little Devil", page 15.

[image: chapter 42 page 15]

Comment: i think i should start reading the manga

Comment: yes you should :D